# IF function condition with REGEXMATCH returns wrong result

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

The value of the cells are:

| D | F | R |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Marco Marques (+19091234567) | 06/19/2023_Purchase: (Footlocker) Spiderman All Terrain Clog Size 12 | win |

The output: `Not Counted`

I don't understand why it returns  "Not Counted" when the conditions are all False.

My formula is:

```
=IF(
  OR(
    $R3322="justApplicable",
    $R3322="notApplicable",
    REGEXMATCH($D3322, "(?i).*Lohnes.*|.*Jean Paul Honore.*|.*Burrowes.*|.*Genevieve Taylor.*|.*Safabakhsh.*|.*MVP.*|.*Inside.com.*|.*Mastercard.*|.*Chuanroong.*|.*Raj Jha.*"),
    REGEXMATCH($F3322, "(?i).*Remind.*|.*Recurring.*|.*Account Update.*|.*Account Set.*|.*Account Inquiry.*|.*Outbound.*|.*Magic Inquiry.*|.*Account Management.*|.*Customer Support.*|.*Chat Support.*|.*Concierge Channel.*|.*Daily Encouraging.*|.*Midwest Armor.*|\+1|.*Age Inquiry.*|.*Monitor: Slack.*|.*Magic Subscription.*|.*Transfer: Invoice.*|.*Home Depot Lead.*|.*Accelerator Review.*|.*Weekly Bill.*|.*N/A.*|.*Google Local Ad.*|.*Truck Wash.*|.*Car Wash.*|.*Refill Prescription.*|.*CS.*|.*C S.*|.*Email Clean Up.*|.*Magic Usage.*|.*Dedicated.*|.*Schedule.*|.*Accern.*|.*App Review.*|.*Marco.*")
  ),
  "Not Counted",
  "Counted"
)
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the sample data, there seem to be at least a couple of patterns in the `F` regex that should be in the `D` regex. Try this:

```
=if(
  or(
    $R3322 = "justApplicable",
    $R3322 = "notApplicable",
    regexmatch($D3322, "(?i)Marco|\+1|Lohnes|Jean Paul Honore|Burrowes|Genevieve Taylor|Safabakhsh|MVP|Inside.com|Mastercard|Chuanroong|Raj Jha"),
    regexmatch($F3322, "(?i)Remind|Recurring|Account Update|Account Set|Account Inquiry|Outbound|Magic Inquiry|Account Management|Customer Support|Chat Support|Concierge Channel|Daily Encouraging|Midwest Armor|Age Inquiry|Monitor: Slack|Magic Subscription|Transfer: Invoice|Home Depot Lead|Accelerator Review|Weekly Bill|N/A|Google Local Ad|Truck Wash|Car Wash|Refill Prescription|CS|C S|Email Clean Up|Magic Usage|Dedicated|Schedule|Accern|App Review"),
  ),
  "Not Counted",
  "Counted"
)
```

The `.*` patterns are redundant in this context.